# TypeScript: how to allow only a specific type as method arguments

Tags: typescript

I want to constraint the calling party from entering random strings as parameters to a method:

```
// A class providing strings (urls)
class BackendUrls {
 
    static USERS_ID     = (id: string)  => `/users/${id}`;
    static CONSTANTS    = ()            => '/constants';
    
}
    
// Base class with method in question (GET)
class BackendService {
    
    protected GET<T>(url: string): Observable<T> {
        // ...
    }
   
}
    
// Calling party (subclass)
class UserService extends BackendService {
    
    loadUser(id: string): Observable<User> {
        return this.GET<User>(BackendUrls.USERS_ID(id));
        // return this.GET<User>(`/users/${id}`); // <-- this also works
    }
   
}
```

What I want to achieve is constraining the parameter to BackendService->GET method.

How can I prevent UserService.loadUser(..) from entering a random string and force it to use one of BackendUrls static members instead?

What I've tried so far:

```
type BackendUrl = string;

class BackendUrls {

    static USERS_ID     = (id: string): BackendUrl  => `/users/${id}`;
    static CONSTANTS    = ()          : BackendUrl  => '/constants';

}

class BackendService {

    protected GET<T>(url: BackendUrl): Observable<T> { // <-- ??
        // ...
    }

}
```

But that still does not prevent the calling code from entering a simple string:

```
return this.GET<User>(`/users/${id}`);
```

Edit: Please not that the calling party should be forced to use the BackendUrls class' static members (which are all functions).

Answer (score 0):

You can get part way to what you wish to achieve with const assertions, e.g.

```
const urls = ['/constants','/users'] as const

type Url = typeof urls[number]
// Base class with method in question (GET)

class BackendService {
    
    protected GET<T>(url: Url): Observable<T> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I don't think you're going to be able to write code that validates types against an infinite number of patterns unless you write some validation logic in the method however.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAVwE4BspwLxwNoHID040MAhhDFLgDQEJQCmSlAunCekbMMDAJ4AO9OAFVUmOH0FgAZolRRsEBAFsARo2bB8%20OACF2QkCnboA7gEsYACzjL61sABM45iHACOCerHOQ4ACgBxAFEAFQBKUGModH0QAGt6CEcAZUYAN3MQIQBvYDgCuHzC-iQwGHoQCucQ0IAeUIA%20f2QUAC4RVHCOgHlVBiR0klUUegbGuDzC6bhtOAA6ReKCgF9gNemgA)

Comment: But this solution doesn't force the BackendUrls class' static members (which are all functions) to be invoked?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using an interface instead of type:

```
export interface BackendUrl {

    value: string;

}

class BackendUrls {

    static USERS_ID     = (id: string): BackendUrl  => ({ value:`/users/${id}` });
    static CONSTANTS    = ()          : BackendUrl  => ({ value:'/constants' });

}
```

.. and then used the 'value' inside the GET method.